# Почему браузер не создает куки с JSSESIONID

Tags: javascript

Делаю `POST` запрос на сервер, который возвращает ответ с `Header: Set-Cookie →JSESSIONID=6D52D8B587133F95A216B7EA656708A6; Path=/; HttpOnly`. Но браузер не сохраняет эти куки, нужно ли их как-то устанавливать вручную или почему браузер их не сохраняет?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что куки не сохраняются?

Comment: @Grundy, Проверяю в браузере куки, сохранились или нет

Comment: как проверяешь?

Comment: просто в настройках браузера смотрю, когда юзаю Edge, то там через F12 можно увидеть куки которые хранятся на сайте

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595872/under-what-conditions-is-a-jsessionid-created

Comment: проверь какие настройки для cookies установлены. Возможно они просто запрещены

Comment: @hindmost, как вопрос по ссылке относится к данному, если в ответе сервера явно указано установить куки?

Comment: @Grundy, разрешение на запись куки есть, запретов для посторонних сайтов нет

Comment: @Alex, тогда попробуй другой браузер.

Comment: @Grundy, пробую и в Chrome и в Edge. Одинаково...

Comment: @Grundy, зато в Postman когда проверяю, то все нормально, сессия сохраняется

Comment: Выглядит странно, либо ты куда-то не туда смотришь, либо одно из двух :)

Comment: @Grundy, это может быть из-за CORS?

Comment: @Alex, а в консоли есть соответствующая ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy, была, но устранил после добавления CORSFilter

Comment: После этого куки стали записываться?

Comment: @Grundy, заметил, что когда отключаю CORSFilter, то куки записываются. Но если отключить фильтр, то не могу делать запросы из браузера, ибо CORS начинает свои ошибки выдавать